# Send premium-emoji with Pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I need to send a premium emoji on the user's account using Pyrogram. I tried to send with `send_message()` a list of `MessageEntityCustomEmoji` and `MessageEntity`. The first one gave the error `'MessageEntityCustomEmoji' object has no attribute '_client'`, and the second one sent a message without an emoji. How do I send them without errors?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of research and suffering, the answer was:

```
...

my_emoji_str = "<emoji id=5310129635848103696>✅</emoji> And this is custom emoji in the text"
await app.send_message(message.chat.id, my_emoji_str)
```

This is basically a text formatting, here it is in HTML ParseMode of Pyrogram, but Pyrogram supports both Markdown and HTML formatting simultaneously out-of-the-box, and you also **don't** need to specify it in the `parse_mode` argument.

And the `id` is the `custom_emoji_id` that you can find in the `message` object if you don't know it yet. To know what to look for:

```
...
"text": "✅ Hello",
"entities": [
    {
        "_": "MessageEntity",
        "type": "MessageEntityType.CUSTOM_EMOJI",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 1,
        "custom_emoji_id": 5310129635848103696 # <-- here you go
    }
],
...
```

And.. That's it!